# Does not have a member named ( Swift )

Tags: swift, swift-playground, swift-extensions

I have two labels (CountryCode, CountryName) in prototype cells, and I created a class for them called " CountryCell " and I created the TableViewController class called " CountriesVC " I made the labels' outlets in the CountryCell but I want to use them in CountriesVC and when I do so it reports an error that says 'CountriesVC' Does not have a member named 'CountryCode' .

Thanks a lot.

Here is the code where I want to use CountryCode and CountryName

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ChangeCountryCode" {

            SelectedCCode = self.CountryCode.text
            SelectedCName = self.CountryName.text

        }
    }
```

Here is CountryCell code :

```
class CountryCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var CountryCode: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var CountryName: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Comment: Also I want to use the CountryCode and CountryName for the selected cell how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These properties that you are trying to access are not declared in the current class. You must first create a variable of type "CountryCell" and then access the properties of that class.